# Example of two Scrapy spiders, one has a memory leak and I can't find it

Tags: python, parsing, scrapy, bots

This is driving me nuts. It drove me to consolidate and simplify a lot of code, but I just can't fix the problem. Here is an example of two spiders I wrote. The top one has a memory leak that causes the memory to slowly expand until its full.

They are almost Identical and they use the same items and everything else outside of the spider so I do not think there is anything in the rest of my code to blame. I have also isolated bits of code here and there, tried deleting variables towards the end. I've looked over the scrapy docs and I am still stumped. Anyone have any magic to work?

```
import scrapy
from wordscrape.items import WordScrapeItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
import json


class EnglishWikiSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name='englishwiki'
    allowed_domains = ['en.wikipedia.org']
    start_urls = [
    'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/wiki/', )), callback='parse_it', follow=True),
        )

    def parse_it(self, response):

        the_item = WordScrapeItem()
        # This takes all the text that is in that div and extracts it, only the text, not html tags (see: //text())
        # if it meets the conditions of my regex
        english_text = response.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]//text()').re(ur'[a-zA-Z\'-]+')

        english_dict = {}
        for i in english_text:
            if len(i) > 1:
                word = i.lower()
                if word in english_dict:
                    english_dict[word] += 1
                else:
                    english_dict[word] = 1

        # Dump into json string and put it in the word item, it will be ['word': {<<jsondict>>}, 'site' : url, ...]
        jsondump = json.dumps(english_dict)
        the_item['word'] = jsondump
        the_item['site'] = response.url
        return the_item
```

The second, and stable spider:

```
import scrapy
from wordscrape.items import WordScrapeItem
import re
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
import json


class NaverNewsSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name='navernews'
    allowed_domains = ['news.naver.com']
    start_urls = [
    'http://news.naver.com',
    'http://news.naver.com/main/read.nhn?oid=001&sid1=102&aid=0007354749&mid=shm&cid=428288&mode=LSD&nh=20150114125510',
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('main/read\.nhn', )), callback='parse_it', follow=True),
        )

    def parse_it(self, response):

        the_item = WordScrapeItem()

        # gets all the text from the listed div and then applies the regex to find all word objects in hanul range
        hangul_syllables = response.xpath('//*[@id="articleBodyContents"]//text()').re(ur'[\uac00-\ud7af]+')

        # Go through all hangul syllables found and adds to value or adds key
        hangul_dict = {}
        for i in hangul_syllables:

            if i in hangul_dict:
                hangul_dict[i] += 1
            else:
                hangul_dict[i] = 1

        jsondump = json.dumps(hangul_dict)
        the_item['word'] = jsondump
        the_item['site'] = response.url
        return the_item
```

Comment: How have you identified the memory leak?

Comment: through '$ top' When I am running the first spider I can see scrapy slowly expanding until its maxed, when I run the second spider, it is stable at 2%ish

Comment: What if the first one just finds more of what it is looking for?

Comment: I guess that could be a possibility. I'm not terribly experienced with crawling, but do the spiders just make an unbounded number of simultaneous requests depending on how many sources they find? EIDT: I just looked at the docs and the default simultaneous requests is 16. Could your theory apply to more than just requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Jepio is right in his comment. I think the spidder is finding too many links to follow and therefore having to store them all in the interim perdiod.

EDIT: So, the problem is that it is storing all of those links in memory instead of on disk and it eventually fills up all my memory. The solution was to run scrapy with a job directory, and that forces them to be stored on disk where there is plenty of space.

$ scrapy crawl spider -s JOBDIR=somedirname

Comment: Does the JOBDIR param store the Request to disk? I tried and its creating some data but memory still remains high.

Comment: I think the main question is if the memory is expanding? Before using the jobdir it was perpetually expanding until it was too high for the machine. 'remains high' is a relative term